# Combining two mysql rows with a duplicate id

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database in which users can submit information about how many steps they've taken and I am trying to pull it to make a leaderboard as such but due to it being submitted in singularly, they pull separately.

```
SELECT step_count.steps, step_count.email, logins.FirstName, logins.LastName
  FROM step_count, logins
  WHERE step_count.email=logins.email
```

This is the query and this is how the information is being pulled

```
steps | email                          | FirstName | LastName

5000  | one@test.com                   | One       | onetest
300   | two@test.com                   | Two       | twotest
200   | one@test.com                   | One       | onetest
```

Is there a way to combine the two together to get the total amount of steps?

Comment: Yes, use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`, see the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` aggregate function with the `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT SUM(step_count.steps), 
       step_count.email, 
       logins.FirstName, 
       logins.LastName
FROM step_count, logins
WHERE step_count.email=logins.email
GROUP BY step_count.email, logins.FirstName, logins.LastName
```

In this way you can group by fields that you want to aggregate, and sum a numeric field (steps) for every group.

Take a look at: [mysql aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

You should also take a look to the `INNER JOIN` statement to join tables instead of using the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query :

```
SELECT
    sum(step_count.steps) as sum_steps,
    step_count.email,
    logins.FirstName,
    logins.LastName
FROM
   step_count
   inner join logins on
       step_count.email=logins.email
group by
    step_count.email,
    logins.FirstName,
    logins.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUM() function in mysql. 
 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum
 - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm
Some references above for further information but your query would look like

```
SELECT SUM(step_count.steps), step_count.email, logins.FirstName, logins.LastName
    FROM step_count, logins
    WHERE step_count.email=logins.email
    GROUP BY logins.email;
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use `GROUP BY` by specifying the keys to regroup, and use `SUM()` on `steps` to get the total steps for the key specified in groupBy.

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html